# File is sometimes open, sometimes closed when I try to write data in it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my main file, I call the following function to write same data to a binary file:

**main.py**

```
writeOutputFile(param1, param2, param3)
```

In `file_a.writeOutputFile` I open my output file in a with statement
and call the function `file_b.writeReference`:

**file_a.py**

```
@singleton
class BitstreamToFile:
    def __init__(self, outfile):
        self.outfile = outfile
        self.cache = ''

    def add(self, data, length):
        s = ''
        if (type(data) == str):
            log.info("string %s \n "%data)
            for char in data:
                b = bin(ord(char))[2:]
                s = s + "{:0>8}".format(b)
        else:
            s = bin(data)[2:]
            if (len(s) < length):
                resto = length - len(s)
                for _ in range(0, resto):
                    s = '0' + s
        s = s[0:length]
        self.cache = self.cache + s

        self.flush()

    def writeByteToFile(self):
        if (len(self.cache) < 8):
            raise ("Not enough bits to make a byte ")
        data = int(self.cache[:8], 2)
        log.info("writeByteToFile %s " % data)
        self.outfile.write(struct.pack('>B', data))
        self.cache = self.cache[8:]

    def flush(self, padding=False):
        while (len(self.cache) >= 8):
            log.info("BEF flush len(self.cache) %s"%len(self.cache))
            self.writeByteToFile()
            log.info("AFT flush len(self.cache) %s"%len(self.cache))

        if (padding):
            self.cache = "{:0<8}".format(self.cache)
            self.writeByteToFile()

def writeOutputFile(param1, param2, param3):
    [..]
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'wb') as out_file:
       writeReference(out_file, param2, param1)
```

In `file_B.writeReference` I instantiate my `BitstreamToFile` object

**file_b.py**

```
def writeReference(out_file, param2, param1):
    bitstream = file_a.BitstreamToFile(file)
    log.debug ("write key && length")
    bitstream.add("akey", 32)
    bitstream.add(0, 64)
    [..]
```

When I compile and execute the first time, I get no error. The second time instead I get:

```
# log from `file_B.writeReference`   
write key && length
# log from file_a.bitstream.flush
BEF flush len(self.cache) 32
#log from file_a.bitstream.writeByteToFile
writeByteToFile 114
```

then the code crashes:

```
Exception on /encode [POST]
[..]
File "/src/file_a.py", line 83, in flush
self.writeByteToFile()
File "/src/file_a.py", line 73, in writeByteToFile
self.outfile.write(struct.pack('>B', data))
ValueError: write to closed file
"POST /encode HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Any hints on where the error might be? I do not really understand why sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `@singleton`?

Comment: How exactly are you running `main.py`? What do you mean by "compile"? In Python you typically do not compile the code as an extra step.

Comment: What if you run it a third time? What do you have to do so that it counts as a "first time" and it works again?

Comment: Why is there `[POST]` and `HTTP` stuff in the error log? The code doesn't seem to have anything to do with HTTP.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you for your support. I've found out that my issue was generated by the Docker container where my code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the docker container which handles the code I shared above.
I'm a newby in Docker, and so I was using the following command to build up my containers (I have 3 micro-services):

```
$docker-compose up -d --build
```

without knowing that, if my container is not RE-created (no changes in the source code), the second time I re-run the previously stopped container where my file was closed at the end.

If I force container to be recreated (in the case I do not need to change the source code):

```
$docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate
```

I have no more errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer.**
diagnostic tool:
Subclass `io.FileIO`; override the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods adding logging so you can see when the context manager enters and exits (file closed?).  Maybe add more logging to other parts of the program for finer grained *time-history*. Do some test runs with a fake file or even something more **isolated from your real stuff** (I say this mainly because I don't know the consequences of using the subclass so **you should be careful**). Here is an example:

```
import io
class B(io.FileIO):
    def __enter__(self):
        print(f'\tcontext manager entry - file:{self.name}')
        return super().__enter__()
    def __exit__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        print(f'\tcontext manager exiting - file:{self.name}')
        super().__exit__(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

---

```
In [32]: with B('1.txt','wb') as f:
    ...:     f.write(b'222')
    ...:     
        context manager entry - file:1.txt
        context manager exiting - file:1.txt

In [33]:
```

Comment: thank you for your support but actually I've found out the issue was related to the Docker container I was not recreating.